# How to style specific Items on action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have an action bar with 3 items and want to style them differently (see below image).  The problem is when I set the style as follows:

```
<style name="MyTheme2" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#DAF9FE</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#DAF9FE</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

It sets all 3 items with that theme.  Essentially I want to add a background image to just one Item on my action bar instead of applying it to all 3.

item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/btn_ab_quiz_normal

Is there any way to do this without creating a custom view?

I have also tried having a Quiz Button image with the text as part of the image and set Text="", but the icon shows up tiny because action bar icons are meant to be a specific dimension.

- the below picture is what I want my action bar to look like.

[image: The action bar that I want]

Answer (score 0):

Well the color you can change with this:

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

In `menu.xml` you can add icons to your ActionBar. Like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_compose"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_compose"
          android:title="@string/action_compose" />
</menu>
```

Connect `main.xml` from `MainActivity`. Use this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

If you want that tiny button than I suggest you to open Photoshop and create new item.

I hope it helped... ;)

Comment: Thanks but the setBackgroundDrawable sets the action bar's background, I just want to set the background of one action bar item.  I'm already doing all the things you stated to add the items and inflate the menu.

Comment: Then you should work with photoshop. In photosop you could change items color in 20 seconds. If you need you can check out about ScherlockActionBar.

Comment: I tried photoshopping the image too, but it shrinks it to 72x72 because that is the dimensions is expects for an icon.  I think I will have to add a customView to the action bar.  SherlockActionBar is typically used to support android versions 3.0 and below since the actionbar wasn't available then.